# ListView is not showing up on app

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Image Here]

A quick problem, my `Listview` is not showing up in my app. I just deleted and redownloaded **android studios**, so I'm on the newest version.

```
public class ToDoList extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        notes.add("Here's an example");
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set the adapter to the listview. `listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)`

Comment: sorry, i did that, I guess i just forgot to copy it into here. It still doesn't work

Comment: You can follow this tutorial how to show list on listView in Android: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass your arrayList to arrayAdapter, then set your arrayAdapter in your listview.

**Use this**

```
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,notes);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: @Jackson Ennis you have to add your arraylist into your Adapter

Comment: was not me. Seemed super harsh.

Comment: It worked! I guess I didn't add the (, notes), so it wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set **adapter** to **listview**

add this line

```
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Haha whoops! I actually did, I just forgot to put it in the code for the problem

Answer (score 0):

You must have to pass your `arrayList` to `arrayAdapter`, then after set your arrayAdapter in `listview`.

**Use Like This**

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes );
 listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this instead**

```
ArrayApater adapter=new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,notes);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: **use   R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item instead of .R.layout.simple_list_item_1**

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use this, pass notes to your adatpter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.Define a new Adapter as follow**

> First parameter - Context
>
> Second parameter - Layout for the row
>
> Third parameter - the Array of data

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

**2. Assign adapter to ListView**

```
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```